# Abstract Class to Display Static Varibles

Tags: php, html, css, abstract-class

Basically what I have to do is create an abstract class with all of my variables/shared code in it. I then have to extend the class to make the variables unique to each class that extends the abstract. I'm relatively familiar with PHP but have never dealt with abstract classes and I'm completely lost.

HTML/PHP (index.php):

```
 <div class="card-wrapper">
  <div class="card">
    <div class="card-inner">
      <?php
        require 'Card.php';
        $name = new Card();
      ?>
      <div class="fleft">
        <div class="name"><?php echo $name->name;?></div>
        <div class="business"><?php echo $name->business;?></div>
      </div>
      <div class="fright">
        <div class="email"><?php echo $name->email;?></div>
        <div class="website"><?php echo $name->website;?></div>
        <div class="phone"><?php echo $name->phone;?></div>
        <div class="address"><?php echo $name->address;?></div>
        <div class="city"><?php echo $name->city;?></div>
        <div class="state"><?php echo $name->state;?></div>
        <div class="zip"><?php echo $name->zip;?></div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP (card.php):

```
<?php
abstract class Card{
    public $name = "John Q Public";
    public $business = "Q Public Incorporations";
    public $email = "john@qpublic.com";
    public $website = "jqpinc.com";
    public $phone = "555-555-5555";
    public $address = "123 Main Street";
    public $city = "Bowling Green,";
    public $state = "Kentucky";
    public $zip = "42101";
}
```

Comment: What's Java got to do with this?

Comment: It was a miss click, I removed it.

Comment: You seem to be confusing [abstract](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php) and [static](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.static.php)

Comment: I may be, the project I was assigned to work on was poorly described to me.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I don't want my work done for me but basically I have to display a generic business card with an abstract class and have other classes extend the abstract to make more specific cards.